# Displaying a specific Firestore document in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I want to display only a specific document from Firestore in Flutter. For this, I tried using a `if` statement, but I am only receiving a blank white screen with no data. If i remove the `if` statement, then i am getting all the documents displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fetching whole collection, you can also fetch particular document by this. There's no need to add `if` condition in this case. See below code.

```
  StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("<collectionPath>").doc("<docId>").snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
      return ListView();
    },
  );
```

> I just tried, below code is working in my case.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "test",
      home: Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("<collection>")
              .doc("<docId>")
              .snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.data.data()["fieldName"]),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- Please share your code to test.

> In my case I'm using `cloud_firestore: ^1.0.3`